# Cannot show TrustPilot HTML when inserted with JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, trustpilot

If I added the TrustPilot html code directly on the HTML page, it works fine but I needed to insert it with jQuery. I see the HTML code when inserted  but it's not displaying.

```
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    var el = $('#some-element');

    el.html( trustPilotHtml() );

    function trustPilotHtml() {
      var str = "<div " +
        "class='trustpilot-widget' " +
        "data-locale='en-GB' " +
        "data-template-id='123456' "+
        "data-businessunit-id='123456' " +
        "data-style-height='500px' " +
        "data-style-width='100%' " +
        "data-theme='light' " +
        "data-stars='4,5' " +
        "data-schema-type='Organization'>" +
        "<a " +
        "href='https://some-url.com' target='_blank'>Trustpilot</a> " +
      "</div>";
      return $(str);
    }
});
```

Is the only way of getting the element to display properly is to directly inserted into the HTML without javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it's not the only way.

You should have a bootstrap script in your inside the HEAD part of your HTML (or close to it).
This script takes care of initializing all the widgets (TrustBoxes in Trustpilot lingo) that you have in your HTML.

Of cause that doesn't work if you are injecting the HTML dynmically, so it's also possible to call `window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement(trustbox);` yourself, when if you need to.

Here `trustbox` is a HTMLElement, you could get by using `document.getElementById("some-element")` or similar.

Reference: https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/articles/115011421468

Comment: I never knew about `window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement()`! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs, it had the React version and full code examples

Answer (score 4):

The following  worked for me on a product list page which returned filtered list via ajax

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("trustpilot-widget");
for(var i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
    window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement(element[i]);
}
```

On the first page load all product reviews are displayed as expected, but if the page is updated via ajax call (using filters for example) the reviews are lost. Running the above code after ajax, reloads the reviews

Comment: this also worked for me in context of Shopify Section rendering API where i fetch a product page containing TP widget on another page.